# Problems Clearing a RadioGroup selection within TTimer procedure

Tags: delphi

Getting a strange problem when trying to clear a chosen selection within a RadioButtonGroup. I select my option from the RadioButton list, wait for the timer to kick in and off it goes to call the procedure or function related to that RadioButton.  The selection is cleared but is reselected again within a second.  There is nothing in the called procedures or Functions that could cause this to be reselected so why is this happening.  Now this only happens when I try to use a Timer1Timer procedure to automate a selection.  ( go easy on me guys...I'm a Delphi Dabbler, self taught, not a programmer. )

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Case BakUpGroup.ItemIndex of
     0 : begin
           BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
           //call procedure here relating to 1st radiobutton selected
         End;
     1 :  begin
           BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
           //call procedure here relating to 2nd radiobutton selected
         End;
     2 :  begin
           BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
           //call procedure here relating to 3rd radiobutton selected
         End;
     3 :  begin
           BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
           //call procedure here relating to 4th radiobutton selected
         End;
// even tried to clear here but once the called procedure exits
// the last selected Radiobutton is ticked again
 BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to upload a short video here

Comment: If you to ask a completely new question do that. But when you do, make a [mcve]. Don't expect us to wade through immense amounts of irrelevant code, hoping that you included the important bits. Once you make that [mcve] you'll find the problem I predict.

Comment: Try searching your code whether you assign _BakUpGroup.ItemIndex_ somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

With the code as shown here, what you describe does not happen. More likely the code you are actually using is different, or something else in the system, perhaps a different timer, is selecting an item in the radio group. To be quite clear, if this code in the question really was all that ever operated on the radio group, then you would not see the behaviour that you report.

You'll need to look more closely at your code to see what you are missing. Try to cut the code down to a minimal reproduction. I predict that once you do that, the mistake will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I just produced a simple working example:

- First I dropped a `TRadioButtonGroup` on the form and added 5 items to the radio group.
- Then I dropped a `TTimer` to the form and set the `Enabled` property to `False`

Then I added and coded the following events:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := -1;
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Either I am missing something obvious here or it is likely you have somewhere else conflicting with your code which we cannot see.

Also try swapping the order of these lines in your code from:

```
BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
//call procedure here relating to 1st radiobutton selected
```

To:

```
//call procedure here relating to 1st radiobutton selected
BakUpGroup.ItemIndex := -1;  //clear the selection
```